# XSL - counting nodes depending on parents' position

Tags: xslt

I am trying to count nodes depending on the position of their parents.

This is an example :

```
<tbody>
    <row>
        <entry>L1C1</entry>
        <entry>L1C2</entry>
        <entry>L1C3</entry>
    </row>
    <row>
        <entry>L2C1</entry>
        <entry morerows="1">L2C2</entry>
        <entry>L2C3</entry>
    </row>
    <row>
        <entry>L3C1</entry>
        <entry>L3C3</entry>
    </row>
</tbody>
```

For each `entry`, I want to count the number of `entry` elements of preceding `row` elements whose attribute `morerows` is greater than a number which depends of the position of the row.

I have something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="nbRows">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(ancestor::tbody/row)">
    </xsl:value-of>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="count(parent::row/preceding-sibling::row/entry[@morerows &gt; ($nbRows - count(current()/../preceding-sibling::row))])">
</xsl:variable>"/>
```

But as you can imagine, this does not work.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please can you write in English what you want the transform to do?

Comment: I just want to know the number of entry elements of preceding row elements whose attribute morerows is greater than (the number of rows - the position of the row + 1 ). Depending on this number, I will perform or not another tranformation. In this case, I will add an empty <td> in html.

Comment: Given your example, what would be the resulting number for each row?

Comment: This example makes sense for the entry elements of the last row :
number of rows = 3
position of the row = 3 (last row)
So I am looking for the number of entry elements of preceding row elements whose attribute morerows is greater than or equal to (3 - 3 + 1 = 1)
The expected result is 1.

Comment: For me your select looks like it match what i understood you try to do. Only you say  "greater than or equal" but you test only for "greater than" (`&gt;`). Try (`&gt;=`). (Beside of some syntax errors.)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly the question this should do the job:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:variable name="nRows" select="count(../row)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="precedingEntries" select="preceding-sibling::row/entry"/>
    <xsl:variable name="minMoreRows" select="$nRows - position() + 1"/>
    <n>
      <xsl:value-of select="count($precedingEntries[@morerows>=$minMoreRows])"/>
    </n>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output - when applied to the example in the question - is:

```
<root>
    <n>0</n>
    <n>0</n>
    <n>1</n>
</root>
```

Comment: In fact, this proposition does not solve my issue.
If you add a fourth row elements at my example with three random entry elements, I expect to obtain 0 0 1 0 but with your proposition I obtain 0 0 1 1. The "position()" you use to calculate the variable $minMoreRows must be the position of the "potential" entry element and not the position of the current row.
I did a mistake in my calculation so I give a new example: imagine you are in the 3rd row, you want to count the entry elements in the first row whose morerows attribute is equal or greater than 3 - 1 =2

Comment: Besides you count also the entry elements in the second row whose morerows attribute is equal or greater than 3 - 2 = 1

Comment: The two counts give the final result expected.